# Property binding not working in ngFor loop

Tags: angular-material, angular7

When I'm binding my hidden property to a variable it is working but not working when interpolation of binding in a loop of `ngFor` value.

I've tried like this [hidden]="!(column.key)" and also hidden="!{{column.key}}" and hidden="{{!column.key}}" it is not working that way but working when binding direct to a variable like [hidden]="!name"
and name is my one of a Boolean variable.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.key}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [hidden]="!(column.key)"> {{column.key}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [hidden]="!(column.key)"> {{element[column.value]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

The hidden property should work like this because the `column.key` has same value as the name of variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`.

`*ngIf="!(column.key)"` will work

Comment: I already tried it, you cant use multiple structural directives on one element @Shankarlal